# a strange error occurred in the debugging process of this C program, what is this?

Tags: c, file, input

I have this exercise to do, it's simple: read from a file.

the exercise consists of:

- open a read only txt file (specified by the filename string I passed to the function).
- (null pointer check (I checked if f is either null or not).
- I've created a pointer (data) to double.
- I've created the variable "value".
- I did a do...while because when I have to read something from a file (or from stin), it's better to use a do...while.

  - ("i" starts from 1 because if I put i = 0, "3" is ignored by the compiler (i.e the
    maximum value isn't read).
  - I have to dynamically allocate *data, in order to store the value that has been read.
  - because fscanf returns the number of values read correctly, I stored this number in
    "value". it's useful to check if the reading process was executed correctly (i.e if
    value != (size + 1), that means that something is going on in fscanf process).
  - I've incremented i++.
    I assigned the value stored in "value" in "size".

and finally I returned data (it was the goal of the exercise).

error list:

- C1090: PDB API call failed error code "3". on the internet, I've read that it could be caused to cloud services that are syncing local files/folders. Some people suggest to close cloud service activities (e.g automatically syncing to onedrive cloud service, mega, dropbox, google drive, etc.).
- C4024: read_double different types for formal and actual parameter too (it's located in the function call (in the main function)).
- != size_t differs in level of indirection from size_t *. (this error is repeated multiple times).

this is my code:

```
#if !defined READ_H
#define READ_H
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
extern double* read_double(const char* filename, size_t* size); 

#endif /* READ_H */
```

---

```
#include "read.h"

double* read_double(const char* filename, size_t* size) {
FILE* f = fopen(filename, size);
/* null pointer exception check */
if (f == NULL) {
    return NULL;
}

double* data;
size_t value = 0;
size_t i = 1;
do {
    data = malloc(i * sizeof(double));
    value = fscanf(f, "%lf", data);
    ++i;

} while (value != (size+1)); /* I've written "size+1" because since I've initialized "i" with 1, not zero, so I have to evaluate the maximum value of size (it's 3, and if I didn't put "size+1", the check condition isn't evaluated properly */
if (value != size) {
    return NULL; 
}
size = value; 
fclose(f); 
return data; 
}

int main(void) {

read_double("this is a general routine test.txt", 3); 


return 0; 
}
```

Comment: `double* read_double(const char* filename, size_t* size)` says that the second parameter is a pointer to a `size_t`, but you treat it as if it were a `size_t` (no pointer).

Comment: MSVC issues 6 warnings for this code, mostly "differing in levels of indirection".

Comment: okay, I've corrected my program, but now it shows me "access violation reading location" in  the line with fopen function. I think it's strange, because after this line I've written the null pointer exception check.

Comment: Why do you expect `fscanf` to return `3 + 1` when it's only asked to scan one value? The long explanatory comment makes no sense.

Comment: fscanf doesn't scan one value, because it's in the while loop, so it keeps scanning the file until the while check holds true, am I wrong?

Comment: `FILE* f = fopen(filename, size);` ==> `FILE* f = fopen(filename, "rt");`

Comment: If `read_double` expects a pointer to a `size_t` variable, you need to have some `size_t some_value;` in your `main` and pass it to `read_double` as `&some_value`. And within that function you need to dereference it as `*size`. I have the feeling that you don't understand pointers very well.

Comment: @Cheatah you're right, C is hard after all.

Comment: @Cheatah okay, I've corrected everything, now the problem is that once the debugger goes in the line with fopen, the pointer f becomes null. therefore the programs ends in the next loop.